# regex sub ignores end of string character

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex

Why does this python code print `|ab||` instead of `|ab|d\nefgh|`? I am trying to capture the rest of the string after `c` (including multiple lines), but I don't know what I'm missing.

```
import re

s = re.sub(
    "^(.*){1}c(.*){2}$",
    "|\\1|\\2|",
    """abcd
    efgh""",
    flags=re.DOTALL,
    count=1
)
print(s)
```

Comment: Why are you using the brackets `{1}` and `{2}` (which are usually used for explicitly noting _number of repetitions of the character/group that precedes them_, not for numbering capture groups)? They seem unnecessary in this case.

Comment: To expand on that, I think you misunderstood that construct.  I'm betting YOU thought that was identifying the two subphrases as #1 and #2, but that's not right.  `{1}` says "do the previous token 1 time" and `{2}` says "do the previous token 2 times."

Comment: @TimRoberts Yes, that's what I thought. Now it makes sense that my code wasn't working as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There does not seem to be a need for `{1}` and `{2}` here. Simply remove them and it seems to work as you intended.

```
^(.*)c(.*)

re.sub(
    "^(.*)c(.*)",
    "|\\1|\\2|",
    """abcd
    efgh""",
    flags=re.DOTALL,
)
'|ab|d\n    efgh|'
```

Answer (score 2):

The reason you get that output is that `{2}` repeats a capture group, giving you the value of the last iteration.

The first iteration has the part that you want, but repeating it again, the group value will be empty as the `.*` can match 0+ characters.

---

Using `(.*)c` will match until the last occurrence of c. If you want to match until the first occurrence of `c`, you can use a negated character class as well.

If you use a raw string notation `r"\1"` you don't need the doubled backslash

```
^([^c]*)c(.*)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/mQLKnM/1)

```
import re

s = re.sub(
    "^([^c]*)c(.*)",
    r"|\1|\2|",
    """abcd
    efgh""",
    flags=re.DOTALL,
    count=1
)
print(s)
```

Output

```
|ab|d
    efgh|
```